# Is it advisable to Calibrate the Battery on a Macbook?

Tags: macbook, battery

How useful or necessary is it to calibrate the battery on a Macbook (Air/Pro) & if it is, should it be carried out when first purchased ? Does it mean that by calibrating the battery it will also last longer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery has an internal microprocessor that provides an estimate of the amount of energy in the battery as it charges and discharges. The battery needs to be recalibrated from time to time to keep the onscreen battery time and percent display accurate and to keep the battery operating at maximum efficiency. You should perform this procedure when you first use your computer and then every few months after that. If you normally leave your MacBook connected to AC power and very rarely use it on battery power you may want to perform this process once a month.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ian, Do you know of any official steps from Apple or elsewhere to carrying out the procedure or....

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4230

Comment: Although the calibration document (from the weblink you have provided) actually states that it depends on whether your battery is removable or not - as whether calibration is necessary

Comment: That's interesting. It depends on the definition of 'removable' doesn't it? For instance, older MacBooks had the battery that clipped on the bottom, newer ones need to be unscrewed with the crazy tool. On the other hand, Retina Mac batteries are glued in. So what does 'removable' actually mean?

Comment: Yes I agree, it is not clearly defined, perhaps Apple Should update this document, and change the wording so that it is easier to comprehend